# ObjectAid UML for intelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, uml, objectaid

Hi I wonder if anyone knows of any plugin for IntelliJ with similar functions that ObjectAid has for Eclipse. I'm working on the JabRef project and need some UML tool. The suggestion I have gotten is to use ObjectAid with Eclipse however I would much rather use IntelliJ.

Thanks for any help!